# What is the runtime complexiy of Java Comparator?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a custom object, lets say `Person.java` with fields `String name` and `int age`. Lets say I have 100 different instances of object `Person`, which I want to sort with custom comparator, s.t. oldest people will go before youngest. Writing the comparator itself is easy - just implement the compareTo method, and I will put the objects into `List` (or a `Queue` will be better?). However, what would be the runtime of this comparator method? Is it faster to perform some custom sort method itself?

Comment: ... You're asking about the runtime complexity of the comparator, which does a few comparisons?! Or the *sort*?

Comment: A comparator just encapsulates a method that determines the ordering  between two elements.  Any function you implement to sort a collection into some order is going to need to determine the relative ordering between two elements.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the runtime of this comparator method?

It depends on how you implement it(!)   However, if you are just comparing the values of the `age` and / or `name` field in the respective objects, it should be `O(1)`.

The complexity of a sort algorithm is normally stated in terms of the number of comparisons it performs.  So if the chosen sort algorithm is `O(NlogN)` and your `Comparator` is `O(1)`, we can predict<sup>1</sup> that the overall complexity would be `O(NlogN x 1)` or `O(NlogN)`.

> Is it faster to perform some custom sort method itself?

No.  It certainly won't improve the complexity if you implement a custom sort.  (You cannot do better than `O(NlogN)` for a general purpose single-threaded sort.)

- If you manually "inlined" the comparison code into your custom sort, you would still be performing the same operations to compare the fields, and doing the same number of times.
- More generally, the algorithms used by the builtin `sort(...)` in Java 8 and later are state-of-the art algorithms.  You are unlikely to improve on them without significant cost (in dev effort and/or maintainability).

---

This question smells of "[premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)".  Please read up on what that means and why it is (usually) a bad thing.

---

<sup>1 - I don't claim this is a proper proof.  Though I think that a proper proof will give this answer too.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing you are using JDK8 or similar.

In most cases, you just need the following code to do the task you described with a very good performance:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(p1);
list.add(p2);
// adding all elements
...
list.sort(comparator);
```

As an alternative, If you implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, you can use `Collections.sort()` method. For more details, see [List.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) and [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).

**Run time complexity**

The `list.sort(comparator);` line has the run time complexity of

```
O(n) x O(log(n)) x C
```

We should consider 2 parts:

1. `O(n) x O(log(n))`: is related to the sorting algorithm, as described in the documentation of [List.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-), in the worst case, we can expect `n*log(n)`, that's why I use the big `O`, but if the list is partially sorted, the run time is close to `n`.
2. `C`: is related to the running time of the `compareTo()` implementation, as you mentioned, you are just comparing their age, it's pretty straightforward, should not be a concern. So this implementation run time is expected be constant, aka `O(1)`. (this might be what you are asking for)

If the *second point* is true, the total run time complexity should be expressed as:

```
O(n) x O(log(n))
```